# Convert Unix timestamp to timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

How do I convert a Unix timestamp (or epoch time) to a PostgreSQL `timestamp without time zone`?

For example, `1481294792` should convert to `2016-12-09 14:46:32`.

I tried `SELECT to_timestamp(1481294792)::timestamp`, but that gives me `2016-12-09 09:46:32`.

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1481294792) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61345/33877